# Form builder: add dynamic nested group

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have started with Todd's reactive forms tutorial here:

https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms#dynamicformmodule

Then I try to add some nested groups...so I extend the config as follows:

```
 public config = [
    {
      type: 'input',
      ...
    },
    {
      type: 'select',
      ...
    },
    {
      type: 'group',
      label: 'testgroup',
      name: 'testgroup',
      children: [
        {
          type: 'input',
          label: 'test',
          name: 'test',
          placeholder: 'Enter your name'
        }
      ],
    }
  ];
```

then I add my new form group to the existing one (manually, just for testing):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-form',
  exportAs: 'dynamicForm',
  template: `
    <form
      class="form"
      [formGroup]="form">
      <ng-container
        *ngFor="let field of config;"
        appDynamicField
        [config]="field"
        [group]="form">
      </ng-container>
    </form>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-form.component.css']
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() config: any[] = [];

  public form: FormGroup;

  get value() { return this.form.value; }

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.createGroup();
  }

  // i loop over the configuration object and create a new control for each item
  private createGroup() {
    const group = this._fb.group({});
    this.config.forEach((control) => {
      if (control.type !== 'group') {
        group.addControl(control.name, this._fb.control(null));
      } else {
        const nested = this._fb.group({});
        nested.addControl('test', this._fb.control(null));
        group.addControl('testgroup', nested);
      }
    });
    return group;
  }

}
```

after that i add a new formGroup component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-group',
  styleUrls: ['form-group.component.css'],
  template: `
    <div class="form-group" [formGroup]="group">
        <label>{{ config.label }}</label>
        <ng-container
          *ngFor="let field of config.children"
          appDynamicField
          [config]="field"
          [group]="form">
        </ng-container>
    </div>
  `
})

export class FormGroupComponent {
  config;
  group: FormGroup;
}
```

and alter the dynamicField Directive

```
const components = {
  input: FormInputComponent,
  select: FormSelectComponent,
  group: FormGroupComponent
};

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDynamicField]'
})
export class DynamicFieldDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() config: any;
  @Input() group: FormGroup;
  component: any;


  constructor(
    private _resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _container: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const component = components[this.config.type];
    const factory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(component);
    this.component = this._container.createComponent(factory);
    this.component.instance.config = this.config;
    this.component.instance.group = this.group;
  }
}
```

but I'am not able to get it working correctly.

Error:

```
formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

{{ form.value | json }} model looks good...but it seems that the nested group items are not linked correctly to the model...inputs does not update the model.

```
{ "name": "Robert", "food": "Pizza", "testgroup": { "test": null } }
```

Comment: You have to inject and instantiate formbuilder in your constructor

Comment: @dag the constructor of the formGroup component?

Comment: I would say yes...but first, where are you calling `createGroup()`?

Comment: @dag I have updated my first post...

Comment: it seems like your variable `group` is `null` or `undefined` your component is not finding the instance of it

Comment: you are right, when i will create the nested input the group is undefined...but why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152636/discussion-between-robert-and-dag).

Comment: @robert did you figure this out? I am working on the same thing.

Comment: @Chris If I remember correctly the problem was with passing in the group:  [group]="group.controls[config.name]"